# SQL add one word in the middle of one string

Tags: sql

How can I add a word in the middle on SQL

example :

```
order no AB123456 become ABC123456
```

Comment: Your table has one _column_, not field.

Comment: please specify DB you use. String-manipulations are vendor-specific

Comment: `PASTE` is a common function. Or use substring and concatenation. - depending on what your dbms supports.

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL way, `overlay(col1 placing 'C' from 3 for 0)`. Supported by Postgresql, Mimer SQL, DB2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using *Sql Server*

```
select stuff(col1, 3, 0, 'C') as col1 
from   t
```

Here's a solution using *MySQL*

```
select insert(col1, 3, 0, 'C') as col1 
from   t
```

| col1 |
| --- |
| ABC123456 |
| ABC231621 |
| ABC326541 |
| ABC965471 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CZwa01e8)